# How can I delete a list item with a workflow without it skipping the Recycle Bin? [SPO]

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, delete, recycle-bin

I created a very simple 2013 List Workflow in my SPO site using the designer.

It does 3 things:

1. "Delete item in Current Item"
2. then Email "my email"
3. Go to "End of Workflow"

It deletes the item, emails me, and ends.

However, it never goes to the Recycle Bin.  I've checked the first and second stage that are available to me in the navigation and site settings.  I can confirm that a NORMAL delete through SPO in the same libraries sends those docs to the recycle bin.

Is there another way around this?  I need it to go the Recycle Bin.  I don't mind coding it but I have never created a WSP so I don't know that I'm even set up for that.  I've seen Event Handlers mentioned a lot but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use a 2010 workflow in your environment? I ran into this issue a while back, and found that for some reason a 2010 workflow sends it to the recycle bin, but a 2013 permanently deletes it!

Comment: This caused me major headaches and a lot of time on the phone with Microsoft Tech Support, and they never gave me a true explanation, just told me use 2010 workflows. I could not find anywhere documenting this bug (feature?).

Comment: They are enabled.  I will try a 2010 one.

Comment: Yes, let me know if that works for you. It was quite a while back, but I believe that was the only solution for me.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure how to accept this as an answer since it's only a comment.. but I'd like to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to use a 2010 workflow in your environment? I ran into this issue a while back, and found that for some reason a 2010 workflow sends it to the recycle bin, but a 2013 permanently deletes it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you'll require a REST Call like below:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/items(itemid)/recycle()
```

Create the API and call it within your workflow, this way it will work with 2013 workflows.

Comment: The need for this has long passed but I would try this in the future.  Seems like it would also do the job.

Comment: Yes it does. I don't recommend using 2010 workflow as Microsoft don't support any site which has 2010 workflow on them.

Comment: Yes, we have since switched to Nintex o365 (haven't tried this in it yet) but with the changes to SPO with 2016 features rolling out I wasn't sure where 2010 wf's would sit.  Thanks